# What is the purpose of transformation module for Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, memgraphdb

Can someone tell me what is the purpose of transformation modules when it comes to ingesting data from Kafka to Memgraph?

Comment: You have two separate questions in your post. Can you create a new question about the database scheme since it is connected to the transformation modules?

Comment: I've removed that question and I will create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transformation module is a defined program that user can write. It receives data from Kafka and returns processed data in the form of Cypher queries. Common formats received from Kafka are JSON, Avro and Protobuf. You can create transformation modules in Python or C programing languages.

Memgraph has the whole [documentation about transformation modules](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/streams/transformation-modules). Be sure to read it for specific details.